# Why does website CSS display different in browsers

Tags: html, css

Both Browsers:

[image]

As per image firefox looks perfect but chrome is short on some elements at the bottom HTML5 CSS3 why does this happen and how can it be fixed

ive tried -webkit on my universal * style and on main-wrapper but nothing

Comment: We're gonna need more than a screenshot - in this case, a link to the page would be pretty important. Note that the two browsers may have minor font rendering etc. differences that'll add up to large differences in a busy/long design. If you want everything to line up, consider something like flexbox.

Comment: https://www.cottingley-computers.co.uk

Comment: on source there is cottingley-computers-styles also a very few same page styles

Comment: and where would the flexbox go it is quite big but not as big as some wordpress sites most of this i did myself

Comment: You need to read this [ask] and this [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look different because each browser has his own CSS style defined. This styles apply to the HTML markup when no other CSS is defined inline or comes from an external CSS file. That's the reason why a lot of websites using a "Reset.css".

Comment: thanks im guessing that will work also can i re-add my external styles or re-add padding without it affecting all browsers in future il be re-doing all my site i was just adding *{margin:0; Padding:0;}

Comment: Do note that font rendering differences between browsers/operating systems may make more than just a reset necessary.